# Docusign: Obtain the access token

Tags: docusignapi

Ref: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/

I am having an issue on **Step 2: Obtain Access Token**

I am trying to get an access token. However I am getting the following error:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "unsupported_grant_type"
}
```

whether its using c# code or using PostMan I am getting the error above.

In PostMan
URL: https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token
Method: Post

**Headers**

```
Authorization:  BASIC BASE64_COMBINATION_OF_INTEGRATION_AND_SECRET_KEYS

Content_Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
```

Body: I tried form-data, x.www.form-urlencoded, raw... all are the same

```
grant_type: authorization_code

code: My_AUTHORIZATION_CODE
```

I also tried getting the access token in the call back page when I get the Authorization Code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocuSign.TokenEndPoint"];
        var data = $"grant_type=authorization_code=&{Request.QueryString["Code"]}";

        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentLength = data.Length;
        req.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";

        UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();
        var code64 = Convert.ToBase64String(enc.GetBytes($"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocuSign.ClientId"]}:{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocuSign.ClientSecret"]}"));
        req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + code64);

        using (Stream ds = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            ds.Write(enc.GetBytes(data), 0, data.Length);
        }

        WebResponse wr = req.GetResponse();
        Stream receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Response.Write(content);

    }
```

Comment: This looks like C#, how about trying the Quickstart? it will give you a ZIP file that's already has your auth configured and all, it just works. 
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following line was wrong:

```
 var data = $"grant_type=authorization_code=&{Request.QueryString["Code"]}";
```

Changed to

```
 var data = $"grant_type=authorization_code&code={Request.QueryString["Code"]}";
```

I was missing code=

Answer (score 0):

Your content_type should be application/x-www-form-urlencoded